# What was the general workflow for finding/discovering/editing project files in VI(M) before virtual terminals?

Tags: vim, vi

When asked what is the native "VI(M) Way" to explore a directory tree and view/edit files, it is often stated that one would type the relative or direct path of the file being targeted and open it in a buffer, enhanced (I don't know starting when) by autocomplete.  **This implies one already has knowledge of the project structure (where) and files names (what).**  Left out of this is an explanation of how knowledge of structure/names would be gained in the first place... in particular with the constraint of operating in non-virtualized environments.  Obviously there were no "tabs" in 1976 to toggle between a shell and the editor when vi was first developed, not sure also if there were multiple workspaces... So what did project developers using VI(M) use as reference for file names / structure, while Vi(m) was running?

Comment: Many people in this sub hate historical questions which are either light technical or non technical in nature.  But I usually get one who obliges to scratch my itch of curiosity... thanks @franscois P!     : )

Answer (score 1):

Very Old versions of VI : 
use ctrl+Z to goto shell (vi goes background) & do what you need fg get back vi to foreground  & continue working...

less old versions of VI :
use either ctrl+Z either :e command ; depending if you know what file to open

recent VI versions (including VIM) :  completion is present on all those versions
use buffers  :e .  to browse files   :ls to list buffers   use splits & vsplits  if needed to see many files opened at once   else open only one buffer at a time

vim  8.1 & more recent 
use :terminal to open a terminal inside you vim session. so you can use you git or compile or do anything you need....

Comment: Thank you... part of your answer 'ctr-z' lead me to my answer...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879219/how-to-temporarily-exit-vim-and-go-back/1880473

Comment: I still use ctrl-z